# WMI object to get current sessions with client name?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I want to be able to create a powershell script that will tell me, for all RDP sessions currently active on a machine, who the user is, and what their clientname (machine name) is.

I can use a combination of win32_loggedonnuser and win32_logonsession to get the username information, but I can't find the client name in these objects (enumerations?).

```
PS C:\> $logons = gwmi win32_loggedonuser; $lstring = ""; foreach($l in $logons) { $lstring +=$l;} $lstring -match "cephalopod";
False
PS C:\> $sessions = gwmi win32_logonsession; $sstring = ""; foreach($s in $sessions) { $sstring +=$s;} $sstring -match "cephalopod";
False
```

(cephalopod is my machine name, the machine that's logged into the server box)

.

I can see that `HKCU:\Volatile Environment` does have the client name, and the `temp` key has the user name within it, but I can't establish from the keys alone if the session is currently active.

Am I missing an API call that will get me all this information in one place?

Basic requirement: grep out the Task Manager > Users listing for user and client name, where status is active.

Answer (score 9):

There is no WMI interface for this that I know of.

> Am I missing an API call that will get me all this information in one
>   place?

Yep. You can get the data from the Win32 API. From wtsapi32.dll, to be specific. You can write a C program, or you can P/Invoke it from C# or even Powershell.

Since you probably want Powershell, I wrote this for you this morning:

```
# QuerySessionInformation.ps1
# Written by Ryan Ries, Jan. 2013, with help from MSDN and Stackoverflow.

$Code = @'
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
public class RDPInfo
{
    [DllImport("wtsapi32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr WTSOpenServer([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] String pServerName);

    [DllImport("wtsapi32.dll")]
    static extern void WTSCloseServer(IntPtr hServer);

    [DllImport("wtsapi32.dll")]
    static extern Int32 WTSEnumerateSessions(
        IntPtr hServer,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] Int32 Reserved,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] Int32 Version,
        ref IntPtr ppSessionInfo,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] ref Int32 pCount);

    [DllImport("wtsapi32.dll")]
    static extern void WTSFreeMemory(IntPtr pMemory);

    [DllImport("Wtsapi32.dll")]
    static extern bool WTSQuerySessionInformation(System.IntPtr hServer, int sessionId, WTS_INFO_CLASS wtsInfoClass, out System.IntPtr ppBuffer, out uint pBytesReturned);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct WTS_SESSION_INFO
    {
        public Int32 SessionID;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public String pWinStationName;
        public WTS_CONNECTSTATE_CLASS State;
    }

    public enum WTS_INFO_CLASS
    {
        WTSInitialProgram,
        WTSApplicationName,
        WTSWorkingDirectory,
        WTSOEMId,
        WTSSessionId,
        WTSUserName,
        WTSWinStationName,
        WTSDomainName,
        WTSConnectState,
        WTSClientBuildNumber,
        WTSClientName,
        WTSClientDirectory,
        WTSClientProductId,
        WTSClientHardwareId,
        WTSClientAddress,
        WTSClientDisplay,
        WTSClientProtocolType
    }

    public enum WTS_CONNECTSTATE_CLASS
    {
        WTSActive,
        WTSConnected,
        WTSConnectQuery,
        WTSShadow,
        WTSDisconnected,
        WTSIdle,
        WTSListen,
        WTSReset,
        WTSDown,
        WTSInit
    }

    public static IntPtr OpenServer(String Name)
    {
        IntPtr server = WTSOpenServer(Name);
        return server;
    }

    public static void CloseServer(IntPtr ServerHandle)
    {
        WTSCloseServer(ServerHandle);
    }

    public static void ListUsers(String ServerName)
    {
        IntPtr serverHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
        List<String> resultList = new List<string>();
        serverHandle = OpenServer(ServerName);

        try
        {
            IntPtr SessionInfoPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr userPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr domainPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr clientNamePtr = IntPtr.Zero;
            Int32 sessionCount = 0;
            Int32 retVal = WTSEnumerateSessions(serverHandle, 0, 1, ref SessionInfoPtr, ref sessionCount);
            Int32 dataSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(WTS_SESSION_INFO));
            Int32 currentSession = (int)SessionInfoPtr;
            uint bytes = 0;
            if (retVal != 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < sessionCount; i++)
                {
                    WTS_SESSION_INFO si = (WTS_SESSION_INFO)Marshal.PtrToStructure((System.IntPtr)currentSession, typeof(WTS_SESSION_INFO));
                    currentSession += dataSize;

                    WTSQuerySessionInformation(serverHandle, si.SessionID, WTS_INFO_CLASS.WTSUserName, out userPtr, out bytes);
                    WTSQuerySessionInformation(serverHandle, si.SessionID, WTS_INFO_CLASS.WTSDomainName, out domainPtr, out bytes);
                    WTSQuerySessionInformation(serverHandle, si.SessionID, WTS_INFO_CLASS.WTSClientName, out clientNamePtr, out bytes);

                    if(Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(domainPtr).Length > 0 && Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(userPtr).Length > 0)
                    {
                        if(Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(clientNamePtr).Length < 1)                       
                            Console.WriteLine(Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(domainPtr) + "\\" + Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(userPtr) + "\tSessionID: " + si.SessionID + "\tClientName: n/a");
                        else
                            Console.WriteLine(Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(domainPtr) + "\\" + Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(userPtr) + "\tSessionID: " + si.SessionID + "\tClientName: " + Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(clientNamePtr));
                    }
                    WTSFreeMemory(clientNamePtr);
                    WTSFreeMemory(userPtr);
                    WTSFreeMemory(domainPtr);
                }
                WTSFreeMemory(SessionInfoPtr);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            CloseServer(serverHandle);
        }
    }
}
'@

Add-Type $Code
```

Copy all of that into a file named QuerySessionInformation.ps1. Now launch the **32 bit version of Powershell** in C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowershell\v1.0. The code above uses pointers that will not work in a native 64 bit environment.

Now run the script. If you've never run the 32 bit version of Powershell on that server before, you will need to modify the script execution policy with Set-ExecutionPolicy, as 32 bit and 64 bit Powershell have separate execution policies. Note that there should be no output from the script itself, as all it is doing is compiling the .NET code and adding it to the current environment. Also note that once a type is added with Add-Type, you can not unload it without exiting that Powershell session... AFAIK. It makes debugging this sort of stuff really annoying as you have to restart Powershell every time you modify the code.

Now that the code is loaded, type this:

```
PS C:\> [RDPInfo]::ListUsers("REMOTESERVER")
```

If there are any active user sessions on REMOTESERVER, the output will look like this:

```
DOMAIN\UserName  SessionID: 2    ClientName: RYAN-PC
```

This will work on remote computers as well as the local computer, but beware that if the user running this does not have sufficient permissions to the remote computer, it will fail silently (no output.)

Edit: There are other bits of info in WTS_INFO_CLASS that may be of interest to you, such as WTSConnectState and WTSClientAddress. All you have to do is query for them.

Edit: I have also converted this solution to native code (C) for use on the command line:

http://www.myotherpcisacloud.com/post/2013/01/16/Usersexe-v1003.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Would [PS Terminal Services](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/PSTerminalServices) (for Powershell) do the trick? I use this *all the time* on our 10 Terminal Servers.

1. Download it and install it from this link
2. `PS > Import-Module PSTerminalServices`
3. `PS > Get-tssession -computername {name}`

This is a wonderful utility.

Answer (score 1):

Execute quser /server:[the servers name]   >[the path to the text file].txt

It lists all of the info, pipes it to a space delimited text file so it can easily be imported & dissected. Works great and avoids any complexities of calling native APIs that are 32 or 64 bit dependent. Can be done all in managed code if it's a .Net focused app.

Comment: On a modern Windows system this gets access is denied without special registry settings.

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks for the script.

I found one limitation ; Because of "Console.WriteLine", it's not possible to pipe the result (in a Select-String for example).
I've modified your class to be able to do so. The method Listuser returns a List

Once the Class is loaded then just call [RDPInfo]::NEW().listusers("myserver")
And then you can pipe the result.

```
# QuerySessionInformation.ps1
# Written by Ryan Ries, Jan. 2013, with help from MSDN and Stackoverflow.
# Modified lolix2 Jan 2019.

$Code = @'
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
public class RDPInfo
{
List<String> resultList = new List<string>();

[DllImport("wtsapi32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr WTSOpenServer([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] String pServerName);

[DllImport("wtsapi32.dll")]
static extern void WTSCloseServer(IntPtr hServer);

[DllImport("wtsapi32.dll")]
static extern Int32 WTSEnumerateSessions(
    IntPtr hServer,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] Int32 Reserved,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] Int32 Version,
    ref IntPtr ppSessionInfo,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] ref Int32 pCount);

[DllImport("wtsapi32.dll")]
static extern void WTSFreeMemory(IntPtr pMemory);

[DllImport("Wtsapi32.dll")]
static extern bool WTSQuerySessionInformation(System.IntPtr hServer, int sessionId, WTS_INFO_CLASS wtsInfoClass, out System.IntPtr ppBuffer, out uint pBytesReturned);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
private struct WTS_SESSION_INFO
{
    public Int32 SessionID;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    public String pWinStationName;
    public WTS_CONNECTSTATE_CLASS State;
}

public enum WTS_INFO_CLASS
{
    WTSInitialProgram,
    WTSApplicationName,
    WTSWorkingDirectory,
    WTSOEMId,
    WTSSessionId,
    WTSUserName,
    WTSWinStationName,
    WTSDomainName,
    WTSConnectState,
    WTSClientBuildNumber,
    WTSClientName,
    WTSClientDirectory,
    WTSClientProductId,
    WTSClientHardwareId,
    WTSClientAddress,
    WTSClientDisplay,
    WTSClientProtocolType
}

public enum WTS_CONNECTSTATE_CLASS
{
    WTSActive,
    WTSConnected,
    WTSConnectQuery,
    WTSShadow,
    WTSDisconnected,
    WTSIdle,
    WTSListen,
    WTSReset,
    WTSDown,
    WTSInit
}

public IntPtr OpenServer(String Name)
{
    IntPtr server = WTSOpenServer(Name);
    return server;
}

public void CloseServer(IntPtr ServerHandle)
{
    WTSCloseServer(ServerHandle);
}

public List<String> ListUsers(String ServerName)
{
    IntPtr serverHandle = IntPtr.Zero;

    serverHandle = OpenServer(ServerName);

    try
    {
        IntPtr SessionInfoPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr userPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr domainPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr clientNamePtr = IntPtr.Zero;
        Int32 sessionCount = 0;
        Int32 retVal = WTSEnumerateSessions(serverHandle, 0, 1, ref SessionInfoPtr, ref sessionCount);
        Int32 dataSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(WTS_SESSION_INFO));
        Int32 currentSession = (int)SessionInfoPtr;
        uint bytes = 0;
        if (retVal != 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < sessionCount; i++)
            {
                WTS_SESSION_INFO si = (WTS_SESSION_INFO)Marshal.PtrToStructure((System.IntPtr)currentSession, typeof(WTS_SESSION_INFO));
                currentSession += dataSize;

                WTSQuerySessionInformation(serverHandle, si.SessionID, WTS_INFO_CLASS.WTSUserName, out userPtr, out bytes);
                WTSQuerySessionInformation(serverHandle, si.SessionID, WTS_INFO_CLASS.WTSDomainName, out domainPtr, out bytes);
                WTSQuerySessionInformation(serverHandle, si.SessionID, WTS_INFO_CLASS.WTSClientName, out clientNamePtr, out bytes);

                if(Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(domainPtr).Length > 0 && Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(userPtr).Length > 0)
                {
                    if(Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(clientNamePtr).Length < 1) 
                        resultList.Add(Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(domainPtr) + "\\" + Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(userPtr) + "\tSessionID: " + si.SessionID + "\tClientName: n/a");

                    else
                        resultList.Add(Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(domainPtr) + "\\" + Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(userPtr) + "\tSessionID: " + si.SessionID + "\tClientName: " + Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(clientNamePtr));

                }
                WTSFreeMemory(clientNamePtr);
                WTSFreeMemory(userPtr);
                WTSFreeMemory(domainPtr);
            }
            WTSFreeMemory(SessionInfoPtr);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        resultList.Add("Exception: " + ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        CloseServer(serverHandle);
    }
    return resultList;
}
}
'@

Add-Type $Code
```

Answer (score 0):

http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2003/12/30/Managing-Terminal-Services-Sessions-Remotely.aspx

might be more useful to you :)

Comment: `qwinsta` outputs the device name as `rdp-tcp#0`, etc; not the client name, or client connecting machine name. So this doesn't help me.

Comment: yeah it's a bit of pickle really. You may have to look to the security audit events, although that may be a bit of a pain.