Match output of query user to MS 365 account
Im trying to understand the format of data that in the username column of the output of the 'query user' command on a Windows machine that is Azure AD joined.
I cant match it to any attribute in Azure AD that I can find. What it appears to be for this particular tenant I'm looking at is their displayname, with the spaces removed.
Does anyone know what attribute this is linked to exactly or how this string is derived?

What is the OS language and regional settings language? You may want to try a different mechanism to compare the results. Accessing the Windows API directly may yield different results. https://serverfault.com/questions/342533/wmi-object-to-get-current-sessions-with-client-name

English Australia and Australia are the settings. Unfortunately this is an attribute that our management platform parses so I need to work with it as-is.
